# Calculate average of some columns, not counting null values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with some readings that looks like this:

```
id  foo   bar   baz   qux
1   2     4     NULL  3            
2   6     11    0     2
```

I want to calculate an average of some columns, not including null values in the count. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
select (foo+bar+baz)/countNonNulls(foo,bar,baz) AS result 
  FROM readings WHERE id=1;
```

I.e, my expected result is (2+4)/2 = 3.

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL query?

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes indicative of poor design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use:

```
select (coalesce(foo, 0) + coalesce(bar, 0) + coalesce(baz, 0) /
        ((foo is not null) + (bar is not null) + (baz is not null))
       ) as average
```

Note that this assumes that at least one value is not null, to prevent division by 0.

To handle the general case, you can use case:

```
select (case when coalesce(foo, bar, bz) is not null
             then (coalesce(foo, 0) + coalesce(bar, 0) + coalesce(baz, 0) /
                   ((foo is not null) + (bar is not null) + (baz is not null))
                  )
        end) as average
```

Comment: why add coalesce around the original values?

Comment: @MMacdonald . . . If you add a `NULL` value to another number, you will get a `NULL` value.  `NULL` is *not* treated as zero (although in aggregation functions such as `sum()` `NUL` values are ignored and hence are treated the same way as 0).

Answer (score 0):

try the where clause: where [nameColumn] is not null